How can I optimize Firebase Firestore request when there are thousands of documents?
I developed a web page in NextJS that gets surveys stored in a Firestore database and renders the data as different charts, this page is used by some clients which generates some surveys per month, but there is one client that generates thousands of surveys and is increasing the loading time of the page because of this and the current approach it uses to get the data from the db, below you can see the function that does that:
export const getBusinessDataFromUser = async (userId: string) => {
    const userDocRef = doc(getFirebase().db, USERS_COLLECTION_NAME, userId || '');

    try {
        const [userDocSnap, businessDocSnap] = await Promise.all([
            getDoc(userDocRef),
            getBusinessDocSnap(userId)
        ]);

        const userData: User = userDocSnap.data() as User;
        const businessData: Business = businessDocSnap.data() as Business;

        const response = {
            ...businessData,
            parentId: userData.businessId,
            Id: userData.businessId,
            customers: [] as Customer[],
            feedbacks: [] as (Feedback | FeedbackHooters)[],
            sucursales: [] as Branch[],
            meseros: [] as Waiter[]
        };

        response.Icono = await getBusinessIcon(businessData);
        await Promise.all([
            fetchCustomersAndFeedbacks(response, businessDocSnap.ref, businessData),
            fetchBranches(response, businessDocSnap.ref, userData.businessId, businessData),
            fetchMainWaiters(response, businessDocSnap.ref, businessData)
        ]);

        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error al obtener información del negocio:', error);
        return null;
    }
};

async function fetchCustomersAndFeedbacks(response: any, businessDocRef: DocumentReference, businessData: Business) {
    const customersQuery = collection(businessDocRef, 'customers');
    const customersSnapshot = await getDocs(customersQuery);

    await Promise.all(customersSnapshot.docs.map(async (customerDoc) => {
        const customerData = customerDoc.data() as Customer;
        const customerFeedbacksQuery = collection(customerDoc.ref, 'feedbacks');
        const customerFeedbacksSnapshot = await getDocs(customerFeedbacksQuery);
        let feedbacks: (Feedback | FeedbackHooters)[] = [];

        customerFeedbacksSnapshot.docs.forEach((feedbackDoc) => {
            const feedbackData = feedbackDoc.data();
            if (businessData.parentId === 'hooters') {
                feedbacks.push({...feedbackData as FeedbackHooters, Visits: feedbacks.length});
            } else {
                feedbacks.push({...feedbackData as Feedback, Visits: feedbacks.length});
            }
        });
        response.customers.push({
            ...customerData,
            feedbacks: feedbacks
        });
    }));
}

async function fetchBranches(response: any, businessDocRef: DocumentReference, parentId: string, businessData: Business) {
    const branchesSnapshot = await getDocs(collection(businessDocRef, 'sucursales'));
    const branchesData = await Promise.all(branchesSnapshot.docs.map(async (branchDoc) => {
        const branchData = branchDoc.data() as Branch;
        const branch = {
            ...branchData,
            parentId: parentId,
            customers: [] as Customer[],
            feedbacks: [] as (Feedback | FeedbackHooters)[],
            meseros: [] as Waiter[]
        };
        await Promise.all([
            fetchCustomersAndFeedbacks(branch, branchDoc.ref, businessData),
            fetchWaiters(branch, branchDoc.ref, businessData)
        ]);
        return branch;
    }));
    response.sucursales = branchesData;
}

async function fetchWaiters(branch: any, branchDocRef: DocumentReference, businessData: Business) {
    const waitersSnapshot = await getDocs(collection(branchDocRef, 'meseros'));
    await Promise.all(waitersSnapshot.docs.map(async (waiterDoc) => {
        const waiterData = waiterDoc.data() as Waiter;
        const waiter = {
            ...waiterData,
            customers: [] as Customer[],
            feedbacks: [] as (Feedback | FeedbackHooters)[]
        };
        await fetchCustomersAndFeedbacks(waiter, waiterDoc.ref, businessData);
        branch.meseros.push(waiter);
    }));
}

async function fetchMainWaiters(response: any, businessDocRef: DocumentReference, businessData: Business) {
    const waitersSnapshot = await getDocs(collection(businessDocRef, 'meseros'));
    const waitersData = await Promise.all(waitersSnapshot.docs.map(async (waiterMainDoc) => {
        const waiterData = waiterMainDoc.data() as Waiter;
        const waiter = {
            ...waiterData,
            customers: [] as Customer[],
            feedbacks: [] as Feedback[]
        };
        await fetchCustomersAndFeedbacks(waiter, waiterMainDoc.ref, businessData);

        return waiter;
    }));

    response.meseros = waitersData;
}

async function getBusinessDocSnap(userId: string) {
    const userDocRef = doc(getFirebase().db, USERS_COLLECTION_NAME, userId || '');
    const userDocSnap = await getDoc(userDocRef);
    const userData: User = userDocSnap.data() as User;
    const businessDocRef = doc(getFirebase().db, DASHBOARD_COLLECTION_NAME, userData.businessId || '');
    return getDoc(businessDocRef);
}

The function fetchCustomersAndFeedbacks is the one that gets the surveys from the feedback collection for each customer on each branch and waiter collection of the client, the line that takes a lot of time to finish is const customerFeedbacksSnapshot = await getDocs(customerFeedbacksQuery);. This approach makes the function to trows the error Too many outstanding requests.
So I would like some help to optimize the way I retrieve this data from Firebase taking into account that this client has thousands of surveys since the day it's using my product, also I have to say that right now I want to get all the data at once to then use it to filter it by date and interact with the data without loading times, just the loading time when the page loads the first time, so feel free to suggest a different aproach you consider better.
Thank you in advance.

Loading all documents from the server to then filter them client-side to the ones the user is interested is wasteful. Even if you manage to make it faster, where do you put the limit? At 10,000 documents? 100,000? It just won't scale, nor perform.
Whenever you are loading thousands of documents for a single user request, something is wrong with your data model. Your app should only load data that the user actually interacts with, and the user isn't gonna be looking at all data in all those documents.
So:

Use a limit to only get the first N documents from the server, and
Use pagination in case you want to allow the user to scroll to the next N documents.
Use a query to only retrieve the documents that the user is interested in from the server.


Got it, I will give it a try with the recommendations you gave me, thank you!
